# What can i use instead of Array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that auto populate form (3 fields) and it does work as i wanted (previously), but now, when i have like 2000 inputs, i can not handle it anymore. What i want to do is, make auto populate script where i can add more information later, for new inputs, now, i would need to start changing numbers for each input, i believe you'll understand batter through my code:

Javascript:

```
var ids = new Array();
var use = new Array();
var ful = new Array();

ids[0] = "";
use[0] = "";
ful[0] = "";

ids[1] = "test1";
use[1] = "test2";
ful[1] = "test3";


ids[2] = "test1";
use[2] = "test";
ful[2] = "test3";

ids[3] = "test1";
use[3] = "test2";
ful[3] = "test3";

ids[4] = "test1";
use[4] = "test2";
ful[4] = "test3";

function Choice() {
//x = document.getElementById("users");
y = document.getElementById("selectUsers");
//x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById("ids").value = ids[y.selectedIndex];
document.getElementById("use").value = use[y.selectedIndex];
document.getElementById("ful").value = ful[y.selectedIndex];
}
```

Form:

```
<select id="selectUsers" class=" outtaHere" name="users" onChange='Choice();'><option     value="0" selected="selected">Choose...</option>
<option value="1">Test1</option>
<option value="2">Test2</option>
<option value="3">Test3</option>
<option value="4">Test4</option>
```

The problem is in, if i try to add new option value on 2nd position, with value 5, i would need to change the javascript order again, 1,2,3,4,5, i'm wondering, if i'm able to make the javascript like this and make it work:

```
<option value="1">Test1</option>
<option value="2">Test2</option>
<option value="4">Test4</option>
<option value="3">Test3</option>


ids[2] = "test1";
use[2] = "test";
ful[2] = "test3";

ids[4] = "test1";
use[4] = "test2";
ful[4] = "test3";

ids[3] = "test1";
use[3] = "test2";
ful[3] = "test3";
```

Please note the difference in 3 and 4 ids.

What's the best option i can use?

Comment: you can use a json object

Comment: Certainly there are many ways of doing it. Not sure if any of them can be called "the best".

Comment: Okay, what would you like to suggest me to do? Thank you, Havenard.

Comment: Well you could always involve a server with an Ajax call so you do not send all of that data down to the client.

Comment: I would like to know how to do that, an example please? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what your issue is. Yes, you can add a new `<option value="5">` anywhere in the select, and would need to set `ids[5]`/`use[5]`/`ful[5]` to some values then. Can you explain what does not work with this approach?